# Few rigidbody cause Bullet Physics slowly

Tags: c++, physics-engine, bulletphysics

I'm currently doing the job for intergrating physics engine, Bullet Physics, into my graphics engine, Before that, I implemented the easy collision system with SAP and Narrowphase algorithm, the cost of time was 3ms for SAP and Narrowphase with about 300 objects.

Because of some bugs of my algorithm, I decided to change to the real physics engine, Bullet Physics. So I followed the tutorial by official articles. When I thought I know how to implement in my graphics engine, and the output screen becomes 3 fps.

It seems to be my problem on what I understand. So I make a real simple example to reproduce the lag what I encountered.

```
btBroadphaseInterface* broadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();

btDefaultCollisionConfiguration* collisionConfiguration = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
btCollisionDispatcher* dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);

btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver* solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver;

btDiscreteDynamicsWorld* dynamicsWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase, solver, collisionConfiguration);

dynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0, -10, 0));


btCollisionShape* groundShape = new btStaticPlaneShape(btVector3(0, 1, 0), 1);

btCollisionShape* fallShape = new btSphereShape(1);


btDefaultMotionState* groundMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(0, -1, 0)));
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo
    groundRigidBodyCI(0, groundMotionState, groundShape, btVector3(0, 0, 0));
btRigidBody* groundRigidBody = new btRigidBody(groundRigidBodyCI);
dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(groundRigidBody);


btDefaultMotionState* fallMotionState =
    new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(0, 50, 0)));
btScalar mass = 1;
btVector3 fallInertia(0, 0, 0);
fallShape->calculateLocalInertia(mass, fallInertia);
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo fallRigidBodyCI(mass, fallMotionState, fallShape, fallInertia);
btRigidBody* fallRigidBody = new btRigidBody(fallRigidBodyCI);
btRigidBody** fallRigidBodies = new btRigidBody*[300];

for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
{
    fallRigidBodies[i] = new btRigidBody(fallRigidBodyCI);
    dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(fallRigidBodies[i]);
}


for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    Debug::StartMeasureNumber(10); // my time measurement function & measurement id
    dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(1 / 60.f, 10);
    Debug::EndMeasureNumber(10); // this will report the time elapsed.
    btTransform trans;
    fallRigidBody->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(trans);

    //std::cout << "sphere height: " << trans.getOrigin().getY() << std::endl;
}

dynamicsWorld->removeRigidBody(fallRigidBody);
delete fallRigidBody->getMotionState();
delete fallRigidBody;

dynamicsWorld->removeRigidBody(groundRigidBody);
delete groundRigidBody->getMotionState();
delete groundRigidBody;


delete fallShape;

delete groundShape;


delete dynamicsWorld;
delete solver;
delete collisionConfiguration;
delete dispatcher;
delete broadphase;
```

In the above code, I just modified the [Hello World tutorial](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Hello_World) in the last of the page. The code that produce extremelty slow on **stepSimulation**. The different what I did is to add **300 rigid bodies** to **dynamicsWorld**. Also provide the debug information below.

1138ms,634ms,386ms,297ms,247ms,217ms,211ms,192ms,175ms,163ms,156ms,149ms
147ms,147ms,137ms,137ms,133ms,126ms,128ms,123ms,126ms,127ms,119ms,119ms,115ms
116ms,114ms,114ms,114ms,118ms,120ms,108ms,107ms,107ms,109ms,103ms,105ms,102ms
115ms,106ms,102ms,99ms,99ms,96ms,94ms,93ms,93ms,97ms,94ms,94ms,89ms,90ms,89ms
90ms,90ms,87ms,87ms,84ms,85ms,86ms,92ms,88ms,84ms,85ms,83ms,110ms,86ms,84ms
83ms,85ms,82ms,89ms,80ms,80ms,77ms,76ms,81ms,75ms,78ms,79ms,75ms,77ms,78ms,
76ms,78ms,79ms,75ms,77ms,74ms,74ms,73ms,72ms,78ms,72ms,71ms,72ms,73ms,73ms,
77ms,77ms,71ms,70ms,71ms,68ms,71ms,71ms,73ms,69ms,68ms,67ms,67ms,66ms,68ms
71ms,74ms,66ms,66ms,65ms,65ms,66ms,67ms,64ms,65ms,63ms,66ms,64ms,65ms,63ms
67ms,64ms,63ms,62ms,66ms,63ms,61ms,63ms,62ms,64ms,61ms,63ms,61ms,61ms,64ms
65ms,61ms,63ms,65ms,63ms,62ms,61ms,60ms,61ms,63ms,60ms,61ms,61ms,62ms,60ms,
62ms,65ms,60ms,61ms

Before 35th loop, it is extreme slow, and for the time being after that, it is going to be stable on 60 ms. But this is also slow for a graphics loop cycle to handle, So where am I understand wrong in the Hello World tutorial? I need someone to help me out :(

Comment: Did you measure with the debug or with the release version of the library?

Comment: @BDL, I build the library in Debug version for myself, or I need to Rebuild to release mode? My *.lib file like these **Bullet3Geometry_Debug.lib**, **BulletCollision_Debug.lib** ...

Comment: There can be a huge performance difference between debug and release version. Rebuild everything (the libraries and your own application) in Release mode and measure the timings again.

Comment: @BDL, Wow, that work like a charm! Could I ask a question about when to choose Debug and Release mode? I always build my program in Debug mode before, when or why do you change to Release mode? Because I always just feel safe when my program is in Debug mode that can debug deeply.  But for now, If I want to use Bullet Physics, I need to change to Release mode permanently.

Comment: You should make that a separate question. Might be interesting for other too.

Comment: @BDL, Thanks for reminding! I post it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575482/debug-mode-or-release-mode) if you want to take a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is sloved by BDL at the comments section. 
Just build the project to release version, and `stepSimulation` is run in 0ms!